# Update Performance Point Report from JavaScript

Tags: performancepoint, reports

I would like to know if there is any way to update the Performance Point Dashboard report manually from JS (same as it updates after we change any filter connected to it)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. But i wonder why i couldn't find this API anywhere on the web.

Here's the solution:

***PPSMA.ClientConnectionManager.get_instance().resetView('pps_86db12d10f0549ada13578858953e146');***

this will Reset the View (update).